# Passing Data between two xslt mappings

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

Can you please guide me how to store the data into a variable in one XSLT mapping and retrieve the content of Varialble in another XSLT mapping?

I am looking for this:

Input:

```
< Idoc > 
< Elements >
< /Idoc >
```

The same has to be returned as output also, the whole content has to be stored in a variable as a string.

Output:

```
< Idoc > 
< Elements >
< /Idoc >
```

and variable V1 with the whole content.

I will have another XSLT mapping, where I would like to retrieve the content of Variable.

Is that possible, if so, please let me know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

An XSLT variable is local to a stylesheet and can't be accessed in a different stylesheet.

Perhaps you should tell us what you are trying to achieve, rather than presenting us with a design approach that isn't going to work?

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your reply. 
I hv the input content in a xml, which is modified as per certain rules in my appln, there is a req to add other conditions that are specific to country
Like this,
Existing:
    Std_Input -> Std_Output
New Requirement is not to touch the existing standard one, but to have additional rules passed and create the Output2. I am thinking of an approach
'Step 1: Std_Input->Std_Input + Enable Global Variable (XSL)
S2: Std_Input->Std_Output (Existing)
S3: Std_Output -> Retrieve Glb Var + Std_Output (XSL)
S4: New Mapping'
I need a soln for step 1 and 3

Comment: That's pretty vague but it sounds like a use-case either for creating an overlay or customization stylesheet using xsl:import, or for creating a pipeline of transformations, both of which are standard approaches for XSLT-based applications.

Comment: @Micheal Kay: Can you please let me know  if there is any such solution built, perhaps an example would be quite helpful.

Comment: Can't give you more precise help without a more precise requirement. You'll find copious examples of all these techniques in my XSLT 2.0 reference book (from Wiley).